# Heat equation with heterogeneous heat conduction

Tags: elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, heat-equation, finite-differences

I'm trying to discretize and a heat conduction/diffusion problem using finite differences and I was wondering how to use a discrete heat conduction coefficient defined per cell (instead of per vertex). Would a simple interpolation do? Can I get any reference? I can only find references for cases where the conductivity is continuous or where the conductivity is defined per vertex.

Comment: Why finite differences, if the conductivity is heterogeneous? How would you know that the numerical solution converges to the right answer?

Comment: Well I need to use FD because this is just a term that makes part of a larger system. The larger system is an image processing optimization and this term works as a regularizer, so there is no "right answer"; I just want the best way to do it.

Comment: by 'right', I mean is that the limit discretized version as the mesh size goes to zero will not be close to the continuous one. If that's not important, what type of reference are you looking for: what should the reference tell you in a best case scenario?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure what is the best way to define the conductivity between the vertices. This is probably already in some book but I cannot find it in any! I found some papers but I rather have a more reliable source, this is an old problem. Like I said, most of the times I found discretization schemes where the conductivity is is defined continuously by some function k(x,y) but I don't know what happens when k is discrete and defined for the cell. Maybe I'm not being clear enough, please just let me know.

Comment: I should add that for example in this paper: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfqz12bejmvhjwr/New%20Finite%20Difference%20Formulations%20for%20General%20Inhomogeneous%20Anisotropic%20Bioelectric%20Problems.pdf)"New Finite Difference Formulations for General Inhomogeneous Anisotropic Bioelectric Problems" the conductivity (anisotropic in this case) is just interpolated to define North,South,East,West,etc weights for the finite differences but I'm not sure if this is the best/only way.

Comment: Instead of writing a finite difference scheme, you can always use for this equation, a Monte-Carlo approach because the heat/diffusion equation is a [Fokker-Planck equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/Fokker-Planck_equation). You can thus use the equivalent Stratonovitch differential equation to perform a random walk algorithm in your system.